# I'm getting Java.io.notserializableException error

Tags: java, exception

I'm getting `java.io.notserializableException` error after trying to write an object to a server in a class extending `jpanel` and implementing `serializable` but it worked well if extending `jframe.`

Here is the code:

```
//to send to server 
objectoutputstream out = new objectoutputstream(socket.getoutputstream()); 
out.writeobject(myobject); 

//to receive in server 
objectinputstream in = new objectinputstream(socket.getinputstream()); 
in.readobject();
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide `myobject` implementation. Any serialized object must implement `Serializable` interface and any aggregated object in it also must implement that interface (and so on).

Comment: Please edit your post with correct case. Java is case-sensitive and so am I.

Comment: i was able to trace all other class objects to implement serializable and I finally got the exception: java.io.notserializableEXCEPTION java.lang.object which implies that the object class has to also implement the serializable interface but don't have access to the object class which is a 'universal' class existing in the java library. So how can I tweak that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From [JPanel (Java 2 Platform SE v1.4.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html), it says:

> **Warning:** Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases. The current serialization support is appropriate for short term storage or RMI between applications running the same version of Swing. As of 1.4, support for long term storage of all JavaBeans<sup>TM</sup> has been added to the `java.beans` package. Please see [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html).

Comment: +1 for citing this reference which everybody seems to ignore, but this doesn't account for a `NotSerializableException.`

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of the `JPanel` (the `myobject` instance) has a reference (a private field, for example) to some other object, that is does not implement `Serializable`. And it's that other object, that is causing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

As @Xeon said, provide impl for myobject. As you said that exception is coming on Object class, that simply means either your class or any class-member i.e. field (which is an object, not a premitive type) is not implementing Serializable interface.
Also how do you create myobject there? just directly 
Object myobject = ...
or 
 myobject = .... 
?

Just ensure that everyone implements serializable.

Object class provides methods but doesn't implements that serializable interface, otherwise every object in Java would have been serializable by default !